# Use numpy array to do conditional operations on another array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have 2 arrays:

```
a = np.array([2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2])

b = np.array([0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.9])
```

What I would like to do, is take the value in array `b` and multiple it to the values in array `a`, based on it's index.

So the first value in array `a` is 2. I want the value in array `b` at that index position to be multiplied by that value. So in array `b`, index postion 2's value is `0.25`, so multiple that value (2) in array `a` by `0.25`.

I know it can be done with iteration, but I'm trying to figure out how it's done elmentwise operations.

Here's the iteration way that I've done:

```
result = np.array([])
for idx in a:
    result = np.append(result, (b[idx] * idx))
```

To get the result:

```
print(result)
[0.5 0.5 0.  0.  0.5 0.5 0.  0.  0.  0.  2.7 0.  0.5 0.  0.  0.5]
```

What's an elementwise equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer arrays can be used as indices in numpy. As a consequence, you can simply do something like this

```
b[a] * a
```

EDIT:

Just for completeness, your iterative solution triggers a new memory allocation every time `append` is called (see the 'returns' section of [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)). Since you already now the shape of your output (i.e. `a.shape`), it's much better to allocate the output array in advance, e.g. `result = np.empty(a.shape)` and then go through the cycle.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways to do this, but if you want purely element-wise operations you could do the following:

Before getting the result, each element of b is transformed by its index. So create another vector *n*.

```
n = np.arange(len(b)) * b

# In the example, n now equals [0. , 0.5, 0.5, 2.7]

# then the result is just n indexed by a

result = n[a]

# result = [0.5, 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0.5, 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 2.7, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0.5]
```